# How can I make it work clockpicker in Symfony forms?

Tags: symfony, twig, clockpicker

I'm trying to make a friendly interface to select TIME and save it to database, so I decided to use bootstrap clockpicker.
This is my layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/estilo.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap-select.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/datepicker.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset('public/css/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
    {% set empresa = app.session.get('empresa') %}
    <div class="container header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {% set env = app.environment %}
                {% if env == 'dev' %}
                    {% set app_link = 'app_dev.php' %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set app_link = 'app.php' %}
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{{ asset(app_link) }}">
                    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/logo.png') }}" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h3 class="text-gray">Sistema de planificación de recursos empresariales</h3>
                <p class="text-gray" style="font-size: 1.1em;">Centuria version 1.1<br>
                    {% if empresa|length %}
                        {{ empresa }}
                    {% else %}
                        Potenciado por Symfony 3.4
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_div_line"> </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div id="layout" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container footer navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <p class="text-center text-gray">Derechos de copia reservados &copy MG Datos</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap-select.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ftable').DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                language: {
                    "emptyTable":     "No hay datos disponibles en la tabla",
                    "info":           "Mostrando _START_ hasta _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 hasta 0 de 0 registros",
                    "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "search":         "Buscar:",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing":     "Procesando...",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first":      "Primero",
                        "last":       "Ultimo",
                        "next":       "Siguiente",
                        "previous":   "Anterior"
                    },
                    "infoFiltered":   "(filtrados de _MAX_ registros)"
                }
            });

            $('#ftable2').DataTable({
                stateSave: true,
                language: {
                    "emptyTable":     "No hay datos disponibles en la tabla",
                    "info":           "Mostrando _START_ hasta _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 hasta 0 de 0 registros",
                    "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                    "search":         "Buscar:",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing":     "Procesando...",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first":      "Primero",
                        "last":       "Ultimo",
                        "next":       "Siguiente",
                        "previous":   "Anterior"
                    },
                    "infoFiltered":   "(filtrados de _MAX_ registros)"
                }
            });

            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                size: 8
            });
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                    autoclose: true
            });

            $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                closeText: 'Cerrar',
                prevText: '<Ant',
                nextText: 'Sig>',
                currentText: 'Hoy',
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
                weekHeader: 'Sm',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''
              };
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);


            $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();

        } );
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my new.html.twig:

```
{% extends '@CenturiaMain/Default/index.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% block centuria_menu %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
    <div class = "main container">
        <div class = "row well col-md-12" style = margin-bottom:55px;">
            <h3>Nuevo registro</h3>
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            <div class = "form-group col-md-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.idCambiosplanilla, { 'attr':{'hidden':'hidden'} }) }}
                <div class = "form-group col-md-12">
                    <h5>Fecha</h5>{{ form_widget(form.fecha, { "attr" : {"class" : "form-control datepicker"}}) }}
                    <span class = "text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.fecha) }}</span>
                </div>


                <div class="input-group clockpicker " data-autoclose="true">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30" />
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
                    <h5>Horario: Desde</h5>{{ form_widget(form.horarioInicio, { "attr" : {"class" : "form-control clockpicker-control"}}) }}
                    <span class = "text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.horarioInicio) }}</span>
                </div>


                <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
                    <h5>Hasta</h5>{{ form_widget(form.horarioFinal) }}{{ form_widget(form.horarioFinal) }}
                    <span class = "text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.horarioFinal) }}</span>
                </div>
                <br>
                <a href="{{ path('centuria_cambiosplanilladetalle', {'idCd' : 1}) }}"
                   class = "btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></a>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok" value="" />
            </div>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have followed the instrucctions to use clockpicker, In fact I have created a simple HTML file and It works, But I can not make it work in my symfony application, do you have any ideas regarding my code, what I am possible doing wrong?

[image]

This is my form:

```
<?php

namespace Centuria\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType;

class CambiosplanilladetalleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('idCambiosplanilla')->add('idEmpleado')->add('fecha', TextType::class)->add('horarioInicio', TimeType::class)->add('horarioFinal')->add('extraInicio')->add('extraFinal')->add('tiempoTotal')->add('idAsignacion')->add('fechaRegistro')->add('horaRegistro')->add('idUsuario');
    }/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Centuria\MainBundle\Entity\Cambiosplanilladetalle'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'centuria_mainbundle_cambiosplanilladetalle';
    }


}
```

And It appears like this:

[image]

Thank you in advice.

Comment: can you post your form too please? Did you try to use TimeType in symfony?

Comment: hello hoover_D, I have updated my post, including the form code, but as you can see in the image, It appears like a normal time Field type.

Comment: yes, but maybe in the formtype you have to pass the right variables type like hour for it to be validated by symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form type class, you need to add the "clockpicker" css class to the field, like so

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('idCambiosplanilla')
        ->add('idEmpleado')
        ->add('fecha', TextType::class)
        ->add('horarioInicio', TimeType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control clockpicker-control clockpicker',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('horarioFinal', )
        ->add('extraInicio')
        ->add('extraFinal')
        ->add('tiempoTotal')
        ->add('idAsignacion')
        ->add('fechaRegistro')
        ->add('horaRegistro')
        ->add('idUsuario');
}
```

alternatively, in your form twig, you could also set the "clockpicker" class, like so:

```
<div class = "form-group col-md-6">
    <h5>Horario: Desde</h5>{{ form_widget(form.horarioInicio, { "attr" : {"class" : "form-control clockpicker-control clockpicker"}}) }}
    <span class = "text-danger">{{ form_errors(form.horarioInicio) }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you playitcool, I added that code but when I click on the time field doesn't display the clockpicker, I cant see any changes, you think it is something else?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? Maybe try moving `$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();` to the start of your `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` block.

Comment: Clockpicker can be made to work in Symfony 6 with webpack. I used the jQuery version of js & css & `.autoProvidejQuery()`. Beware, though, that using its `twelvehour: true` setting will NOT provide time input to a form. When that setting is absent and the local timezone expects AM/PM time, clockpicker will provide an input value expressed with AM or PM. Here in the US 24 hour clocks are, unfortunately, not particularly useful.